# How to test -webkit-tap-highlight-color in google Chrome desktop?

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit, touch

How to test `-webkit-tap-highlight-color` in google Chrome desktop?

I'm using this css for an anchor link

```
.close-button {
   width: 30px;
  border: 0;
  padding: 6px;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(201, 224, 253, 0.8);
}
```

I went Chrome device mode to test it, but nothing happens when I tap on link

Comment: The fiddle works here on my Android tablet... By the way, how are you testing in Chrome? When I go to emulation mode, it works there as well.

Comment: Ok, I was doing the mistake. We need to keep the mouse pressed for 2 seconds

Comment: If you solved your problem, you should post that as an answer.